# iTextSharp - xmlworker - html parser issue - removes input tag's ending tag automatically when try to generate PDF from HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, xmlworker

I have following HTML. Look at `input tag` and `comment` below (Real cause of the problem).

```
<div class="col-xs-12 GPAMainForm">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div style="border: 1px double black; padding: 2px">
      <div>
        <table class="table">
          <tr class="border">
            <td class="border">
              <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            </td>
            <td class="border">
               <input type="text" />
               <!--
               If I remove input tag, pdf gets generated else it show error like:
               `Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag input`
               -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Instead of `input tag` I tried to go with `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

---

***Error***

> Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag input

***Cause of problem***

But when I see parsed html, I can clearly that it somehow removes `/` and it generates `<input type="text>`.

same with `<asp:textbox>` it removes ending tag and generates

`<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox2" id="MainContent_TextBox2" type="text">`

Please help.

***Edit Post:***

```
 try
            {
                string htmlContent = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "");// you html code (for example table from your page)
                Document doc = new Document();
                string FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:\\Nikhil Shah\\Projects\\Local Projects\\PracticeDemo\\PracticeDemo\\PDF\\" + FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
                var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
                var cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\myCss.css"), FileMode.Open));
                cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);


                CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl();
                HtmlPipelineContext hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(ca);
                hpc.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                // PIPELINES
                PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer);
                HtmlPipeline htmlPipe = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, pdf);
                CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipe);

                XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
                XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlContent);
                p.Parse(sr);
                doc.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ".pdf");
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\PDF\" + FileName + ".pdf"));
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Maybe you're using an older version of `XMLWorker`? I get the exact **opposite** behavior of what you're describing. I.e. the `HTML` snippet above with self-closing tag `<input type='text' />` parses the `HTML` and creates the PDF output file, but **removing** `/` throws the `iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException` "_Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag input._" Tested using latest XML Worker, version 5.5.8.

Comment: So what to do? I downloaded it through Nuget package manager. And I hope it must be a latest one.

Comment: I'm using 5.5.8 version... Please help.

Comment: Not sure how you're using `XML Worker`, [but this is what I did](https://github.com/kuujinbo/StackOverflow.iTextSharp/blob/master/ProgramCode/XmlWorkers/EndTag.cs). And a [screenshot of the output file](http://postimg.org/image/jc9vs4nwx/). I'm using `nuget` too, so we should have the same version....

Comment: Is it working in your case?

Comment: uuuhhh...yes, that's why I put a link to the screenshot. You can see that _Company Name_ is displayed on the PDF.

Comment: I meant to ask is it possible to use external stylesheet with it? eg. bootstrap.css

Comment: It's possible, but you have to temper your expectations. Complex stylesheets like `Bootstrap` will **not** be rendered anything close to what you see in a browser. iText[Sharp] is a PDF library **first**, so any XML/HTML parsing helpers can't be expected to be perfect...

Comment: Please take a note that I was able to generate PDF. But what I want is, i want to use external style sheet and when I put simple `input tag` it throws an error. Before that every thing was working except external style sheet.

Comment: Can't help with the CSS problem, but **can** fix the rendered server control output (`<asp:textbox>` or other): **[1]** install `nuget` package [HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/), then **[2]** [see the updated code](https://github.com/kuujinbo/StackOverflow.iTextSharp/blob/master/ProgramCode/XmlWorkers/EndTag.cs) to fix the broken HTML.

Comment: Thanks for help. Really appreciate. But I think I should switch to other library for better support.